# Building 2 Different Warehouse Layouts and 2 Different Processes into the same AnyLogic Model

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am working on a simulation in AnyLogic involving 2 Warehouse Layouts (a square and a rectangular one) and 2 operational processes (current labor-based and a new AGV-based process). My goal is to assess the productivity increase of the AGV process for each layout.

One challenge is implementing a mixed process with labor and AGVs based on work type.

I am stuck at how to design a flexible AnyLogic model architecture that allows me to seamlessly switch between layouts and select different processes for simulation.

I would like to understand if I should create separate Agents for the 2 Layouts and separate agents for the 2 Processes and if yes, how to run a simulation on a mixed process. Any help on how my framework should look like would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are a million different ways to do it. For one, see my workshop on this topic: https://youtu.be/OWwjKqKUA1A?si=d800NfanRaSWukvX

Comment: @Benjamin, I did watch this and want to thank you for creating such amazing content. Your videos are a reason why I am trying to build a flexible model so it is reusable. However, my use case involves selecting different "networks" and "flowcharts" based on input. Therefore, I am confused whether I need to create separate Agents for the 2 Layouts (like A_Layout1, A_Layout2) or simply 1 Layout Agent containing 2 different networks. Similarly, for the 2 Processes, whether the 2 flowcharts should be built in separate agents (like A_Process1, A_Process2) or within the same agent (like A_Process).

Comment: its all possible and there is no right answer. Depends on the use case, purpose, your skill level, reusability... If in doubt, start simple